# Vue toggle color and text of button when clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button that I've successfully altered so that on click it calls a function

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" v-on:click="pauseEvent" type="button" role="button" id="" aria-expanded="false" style=" color: #6c757d; background-color: #FEEFB3; border:none; border-radius: .15;">
                Pause Event
            </button>
```

the problem is that I can't get a function to work for color and text change. I have scaled this back to at least console log a trigger when clicked and that is working. How should I properly make it so that clicking will toggle between the current state and another state where color is red and text is 'Resume Event'?

```
pauseEvent() {
      console.dir('paused');
    },
```

Comment: This is about a) toggling a piece of state b) rendering color and text based on state. Try to solve each separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" :style="{ 'background-color': color }" v-on:click="pauseEvent" type="button" role="button" id="" aria-expanded="false" style=" color: #6c757d border:none; border-radius: .15;">
            {{text}}
        </button>
```

You can use Vue data function. [Example of here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

```
        data(){
            return {
                color: 'green',
                text: 'Started'
            }
        },
        methods: {
           pauseEvent() {
               this.color = 'red';
               this.text = 'Paused';
           },
        }
```

Comment: Actually: It toggles to paused/red, but it doesn't toggle back?

Comment: To do this, you can turn on Toggle function and keep the current status in the data. If the status is paused in the function, you can change the colors accordingly.